# Make a nice router with sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am working with a sencha touch 2 application and i want to make a great router with many controllers, as in a regular web application.

How can i do that? For exemple, i want to redirect each url on the specific controller/action as :

```
/:controller/:action
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really well-documented in Sencha Touch 2 docs, but actually there is a way to map URLs to controller functions or define resourceful routes like Rails. This might be helpful for you:

http://jenwendling.com/sencha-touch-resource-routing/

Comment: still available, I think ... http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Router-method-draw

Comment: Not sure, i get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'draw' of undefined